# Should closed questions qualify for Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges?

Tags: discussion, publicity-badges

I've been running a [publicist badge experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist?userid=127880) lately.

I think it is safe to say that there is a strong benefit to sharing most of the questions.

However, is it worthwhile to reward users for sharing gimmicky closed questions like "What's your favorite programmer cartoon?"

Is there a net benefit to the site, or does it bring people to the site in the wrong way?

I think the answer is: probably not worth it. They probably shouldn't count towards sharing badges. As it stands, there is an incentive to share such questions because they are indeed very interesting to many.

**Edit**

- There may be another category of questions that shouldn't apply, such as some locked questions. [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)
- This experiment involved rapidly sharing questions on relevant subreddits and hacker news. This lasted about 9 days and was enough to generate some backlash from reddit. I do not recommend sharing questions in this matter, especially over a prolonged period, as it can impact other communities' views of SO in a negative way.

Comment: Nice, I love [publicist experiments](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/badges/56/publicist?userid=25936) ;)

Comment: It's even possible to get a badge for questions that have been migrated off the site entirely. Use the original `share` URL from Stack Overflow and you'll get the badge on Stack Overflow, even if the question is now on a different site. (For example, I earned [a Publicist badge on Stack Overflow one year ago for a question that was migrated to Programmers two years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist?userid=1114).) I believe you could get the badge for any deleted question if you could somehow convince enough people to click on it.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Wow, now that is some trivia. Nice